# Scrape multiple tables and put some rows as column headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scraped a javascript-driven  site and stored tables from multiple pages into one html document (sample https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AMt6vj6iCrfiJkeriMpDlAObRUVQ4kem here). The tables have no header columns but each row has a header and then the data point - these row headers repeat across all tables.

Here is the PastBin: https://pastebin.com/QSdFU0Ah

I can scrape all the rows but don't know how to make each row header into a column header with the row data as its data.

[image]

I want to look like a CVS:

[image]

```
    with open('tst.html', "r") as all_content:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(all_content, "html.parser")

    titles= soup.find_all('title')

    for title in titles:
    rows = soup.select_one("table").find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Can you share a pastebin link to html

Comment: just added it above

Comment: just added as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nth-of-type (I'm using with bs4 4.7.1+) to pull first column as headers and second column as values under those headers.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('filepath/sample.html','r') as f:
    soup = bs(f.read(), 'html.parser')

headers = [td.text for td in soup.select_one('table').select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]
results = []

for table in soup.select('table'):
    row = [td.text for td in table.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
print(df)
```

---

You could also use csv

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('filepath/sample.html','r') as f:
    soup = bs(f.read(), 'html.parser')

headers = [td.text for td in soup.select_one('table').select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(headers)
    for table in soup.select('table'):
        w.writerow([td.text for td in table.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')])
```

Comment: I pip installed pandas and already had bs4. do i need anything else? I am getting the error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: yes, i changed the file path to what i have on my computer...sample file is in the same folder.

Comment: When I print(headers) and print(rows), it seems to do the intended. just the pd.DataFrame giving me a hard time. i have pip installed pandas. and also tried iimporting numpy

Comment: You could use csv instead